# Is it on-topic to ask which statistical models are applied in E-Commerce?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I would like to gather experience which statistical models are used in specific businesses/ sectors. For example I would like to know which statistical models are applied in E-Commerce or in Marketing.

Are questions suitable for Crossvalidated? Is it on-topic? Is it too broad?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Questions asking for lists of applications in some field or other get closed as too broad—I think rightly, as there's no gainsaying any answer. Look at the list of contents in a textbook on Statistics for Marketing or E-Commerce to get an idea of what techniques are commonly used.